# Trying to create Mac OS X app from pygame hello world

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pyinstaller

I am trying to get the following "Hello world" pygame app to generate a Mac OS X (10.8) app using pyinstaller:

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame._view
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

# set up the window
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello world!')

# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# draw the white background onto the surface
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

# draw a black circle onto the surface
pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, BLACK, (250, 200), 20, 0)

# draw the window onto the screen
pygame.display.update()

# run the game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

The spec file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/ronan/Documents/projects/python/test'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='test',
          debug=True,
          strip=None,
          upx=False,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=False,
               name='test')
app = BUNDLE(coll, name='test.app')
```

Pyinstaller seems to do its job fine and creates a dist folder with test.app in it. It doesn't run however. When you run the dist folder excecutable from the command line you get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Users/ronan/Documents/projects/python/test/dist/test/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in <module>
  ...
  LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

I have had a real challenge getting the Windows pyinstaller working but have got it now. The hardest part is the lack of coherent error messages. I really like python and pygame and just want to cross this hurdle of deployment. Obviously, this is not my real application but I think if I get this "Hello World" working on Mac, combined with what I learned with getting it working on Windows, I should be able to figure most of it out. Also, I think if I figure this out it could be of real help to any other pygame developers out there.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to use cx_Freeze for mac